# Can I develop AngularJS application without html5?

Tags: angularjs, html

I have developed an AngularJS application, it works fine with the modern browsers. But I have some devices which have old browsers and these browsers don't support html5. I can not upgrade the browsers. So is there any way to run AngularJS application on plain HTML or old browsers. Otherwise, I am planning on converting the entire AngularJS app to JQuery, I don't think that this is a good solution at all.

I searched on the internet but didn't find any good resource.

Comment: AngularJS V1.2 is the last version to support IE8. See https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/version-support-status

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an older version of AngularJS if you want to support older browsers. You wont be able to use the newer features of AngularJS like components. AngularJS 1.2 will support older browsers like IE8. There will be a bit of work involved if you have used components by it will be a lot less work that porting over to jQuery.

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie

Comment: Thanks for your answer